# beginner coding question about end of this code

Tags: python

What does the last part of this code do exactly? Also why is self.name equal to name? here is the code below:

```
class Shark:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def swim(self):
        print(self.name + " is swimming.")

    def be_awesome(self):
        print(self.name + " is being awesome.")

def main():
    sammy = Shark("Sammy")
    sammy.be_awesome()
    stevie = Shark("Stevie")
    stevie.swim()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: The purpose of the last two lines is to run the `main()` function if the module is being executed directly.

Comment: _why is self.name equal to name_ I don't understand the question.  It's equal because the code MAKES it equal.

Answer (score 0):

Firs part of your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

**Second question**
`name` is the argument passed when creating a instance of your class. However `self.name` is a instance variable. The value of this is set to `name`. Read more about python classes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: This is simply a function call to the function main()

Answer (score 0):

The last part of the code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

simply means that when this particular script is run as the entry point file, it will execute the `main()` function. If the contents are imported by another script, it will ignore the `if` statement.

```
self.name = name
```

assigns the input variable `name` to the instance variable of the class, in this case it is also called `name`